# How can I know if the message was delivered to a queue?

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm using the [stomp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stomp-client) library and i want to know if it is possible to know if the message was delivered to the queue. Because im implementing a java service to do the dequeue of the messages and an node js to send the messages to the queue. the code bellow shows how I send the message to the queue.

```
this._stompClient.publish('/queue/MessagesQueue', messageToPublish, { })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a `SEND` frame (i.e. publish a message) you can add a `receipt` header and then when you receive the `RECEIPT` frame from the broker you know it has successfully received the message. The [STOMP specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#Header_receipt) says this about the `receipt` header:

> Any client frame other than `CONNECT` MAY specify a `receipt` header with an arbitrary value. This will cause the server to acknowledge receipt of the frame with a `RECEIPT` frame which contains the value of this header as the value of the `receipt-id` header in the `RECEIPT` frame.

However, looking at the documentation for `stomp-client` I don't see any mention of how to receive `RECEIPT` frames. I actually would expect the ability to specify a callback on the `publish` method which was called when the `RECEIPT` frame is received. It doesn't appear that `stomp-client` supports working with receipts. Unfortunately that means there's no real way to confirm the message was received by the broker.

I recommend you find a more mature STOMP client implementation that supports receipts. For example [stomp-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompjs) supports [receipts](https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/Client.html#watchForReceipt).